# Perl - How to read every single line from delimited txt file and process it

Tags: arrays, linux, perl, file, hash

I have a text file which is delimited by ":"

It has 3 fields

field-1-->name of a file

field-2-->source path of the file

field-3-->destination path of the file

Eg.

```
helloWorld.txt:/home/abc:/home/xyz
```

Now i have to copy this file helloWorld.txt from its source path to destination path.

And this needs to be done for all the lines available in the text file.

I am not sure what i am trying is best practice. It did not work however.

Can someone please tell the best way to accomplish this?

many thanks

```
    open FILE, $inputFile or die $!;
    while(my $file_name=<FILE>)
    {
    my ($tmpvar1, $tmpvar2, $tmpvar3) = split(/:/, $_);
    my $command = "cp ".$tmpvar2. "/". $tmpvar1 $tmpvar3;
    exce $command;
    }
```

Comment: That's not because of the typo in `exce` is it?

Comment: Use meaningful variable names, use [File::Copy](http://p3rl.org/File::Copy), indent the code. There's no operator between `$tmpvar1` and `$tmpvar3`.

Comment: split works.  Personally, I would use Text::CSV ( https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::CSV ), especially the functions that allow you to access the fields by name via a hash reference.

Comment: thanks for your comments. But I would like to know if there is a better approach to handle this type of tasks. like using an array/hash which might be a more straightforward and elegant.

Comment: `tempvar` is a bad name, but similarly if you're using meaningful - but numbered - variables, you should probably be using a list instead.

Answer (score 4):

Use meaningful variable names (not `$tempvar`). Once you start using them (`$file_name`), make sure the variable really contains what its name hints (it doesn't) and use it everywhere (i.e., don't split `$_`).

To copy files, use [File::Copy](http://p3rl.org/File::Copy). It comes with Perl from version 5.002.

Indent the code to improve readability.

Don't post code that throws syntax errors to SO.

```
Scalar found where operator expected at /home/choroba/1.pl line 6, near "$tmpvar1 $tmpvar3"
        (Missing operator before $tmpvar3?)
```

Possible fix:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

use File::Copy;

open my $IN, '<', $inputFile or die $!;
while (my $line = <$IN>) {
    chomp $line;
    my ($name, $source, $destination) = split /:/, $line;
    copy("$source/$name", "$destination/$name")
        or warn "Copying $name from $source to $destination failed: $!";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Copy;

open my $file, "<", $inputFile or die $!;
while( my $line=<$file> )
{
    chomp $line;
    my ($tmpvar1, $tmpvar2, $tmpvar3) = split(/:/, $line);
    copy "$tmpvar2/$tmpvar1", $tmpvar3;
}
close $file;
```

Answer (score 0):

The best practice is to manipulate filename and file itself using core modules [File::*](http://perldoc.perl.org/index-modules-F.html):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Copy qw(cp);
use File::Spec::Functions;

while (<>) {
    chomp;
    ( my ( $name, $source, $destination ) = split /:/ ) == 3
        or die "Broken data on line $.:$_\n";
    -d $destination or die "Destination $destination doesn't exist.\n";
    my $src = catfile( $source, $name );
    cp( $src, $destination ) or die "Can't copy $src -> $destination\n";
}
```